# How to obtain 'static' IP when USB tethering?

Tags: android, usb

I'm tethering laptop<->Android for purposes of IP tunneling/VNC.

Because the laptop obtains a random IP in the 192.168.42.* range each tether,  I must manually enter this for the tunnel each time the tether is established.

This is less than ideal.  Is it possible to have Android assign a consistent (that is,  not random) address to each tether?

TIA.

Comment: Are you sure that Android is allocating this IP? It would seem more likely to me that it comes from some router that gives it to the Phone (because it's in the private range 192.168.42.1/24). Also note that this is a private IP, so it cannot be accessed unless the other computer is also in the private network.

Comment: ^^ Yes.  The device is not otherwise connected to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Firewall is OFF (or properly configured), and your network is not set to Public, and if your connection works means it's all good.

1. Having the phone connected and tethered, go to Network and Sharing Center and click on the Local Area connection "Connections:"

   [image: screenshot]
2. On the next screen select Properties, then highlight IP 4 and press properties there and click "Use the following IP address"
3. Put Default Gateway and Subnet Mask exactly as it was in the ipconfig, and for the IP Address, only change the last 3 digits to anything from 1 to 255 That IP will be your new fixed/static IP and it will remain the same even after you unplug the phone.

   [image: screenshot]

If your connection doesn't work, in other words you can't access server running on the computer, this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887621/accessing-localhost-of-pc-from-usb-connected-android-mobile-device/42607979#42607979