# Pixel force tether mode into using static IP

Tags: networking, android, pixels

I am using tether mode through USB, is there a way to have the phone assign a static IP address to a computer. Currently my Pixel will change the computers IP address every time tether mode is enabled, I need it to constantly be the same.

Comment: Potentially helpful pointers.... https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46499/how-configure-the-dhcp-settings-of-wifi-tetheringhotspot-in-android and https://superuser.com/questions/505338/how-to-obtain-static-ip-when-usb-tethering