# WiFi tethering and local server on pc desktop

Tags: wifi-configuration

I have a WiFi tethering connection created with my android device and in my PC desktop I have a web server on 127.0.0.1:5500. In browser of my android device I tried to go in IP address of PC desktop (after seeing that with ipconfig) but the page doesn't load. How can I fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP address `127.0.0.1` is special in the sense that it is only recognized
by applications running *on your computer*.

For finding the IP address of your computer on the internal network,
start the Command Prompt (cmd) and enter the command `ipconfig`.
Under your wireless connection, the address is in "IPv4 Address".

If you find that this address changes on every connection,
you can make it static as described in the post
[How to obtain 'static' IP when USB tethering?](https://superuser.com/questions/505338/how-to-obtain-static-ip-when-usb-tethering).

Comment: I have corrected the text of the post.

Comment: What error are you getting? Try to disable the computer's firewall. Verify that the phone's IP address is on the same network segment.

Comment: Page doesn't no error description. I disabled antivirus but nothing. I don't know what is segment. I'm a noob.

Comment: See [How to enable or disable the Microsoft Windows Firewall](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000551.htm).

Comment: Ok it works if I disable guest and public net firewall

Comment: Usually you only need to disable one of them. Re-enable after tethering is finished. As the problem is solved, please mark the answer as accepted (the V button).